# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, django

this code has this error and I am absolutely lost how to fix it. the code runs fine until it gets to the last object saved in the database and after that it throws this error. the code is a tool that checks the html of a website between 2 points in time to check if it has an error, even if the website is running well and giving a 200 response code

This is the error:

`in check_html print(monitor.url) AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'url'`

```
def run_monitors():
    delete_from_db()
    monitors = Monitor.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    monitors._fetch_all()
    asyncio.run(_run_monitors(monitors))
    check_html(monitor=monitors)


def check_html(monitor):
    start_time = time.time()
    print(monitor.url)
    # The URLs to compare
    old_html = monitor.html_compare
    new_url = monitor.url

    # Get the HTML of each URL
    try:
        old_html = old_html
        # html1.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


    try:
        html2 = requests.get(new_url)
        html2.raise_for_status()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    html2 = html2.text[:10000]

    # Create a SequenceMatcher object to compare the HTML of the two URLs
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, old_html, html2)

    similarity_ratio = matcher.ratio() * 100

    response_time = time.time() - start_time

    monitor.html_compare = html2

    html_failure = False
    counter = monitor.fault_counter
    if similarity_ratio <= 90 and counter == 0:
        print(f"The two HTMLs have {similarity_ratio:}% in common.")
        print("change detected")
        html_failure = False
        counter += 1
    elif similarity_ratio > 90 and counter == 0:
        print(f"The two HTMLs have {similarity_ratio:.2f}% in common.")
        print("no change detected")
        html_failure = False
        counter = 0
    elif similarity_ratio > 90 and counter >= 1:
        print(f"The two HTMLs have {similarity_ratio:.2f}% in common.")
        if counter >= 4:
            print(f"HTML fault detected")
            html_failure = True
        else:
            counter += 1
            print(f"checks if fault persists, current fault counter: {counter}")
    elif similarity_ratio < 90 and counter >= 1:
        print("Fault is presumably resolved")
        html_failure = False
        counter = 0
    monitor.fault_counter = counter

    # Print the similarity ratio between the two URLs
    monitor.save(update_fields=['html_compare', 'fault_counter'])
    return html_failure

def send_notifications():
    for monitor in Monitor.objects.all():
            multiple_failures, last_result = has_multiple_failures(monitor)
            result = check_html(monitor)
            no_notification_timeout = (not monitor.last_notified) or \
                                      monitor.last_notified < timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
            if multiple_failures and no_notification_timeout and monitor.is_active:
                _send_notification(monitor, last_result)
            if result:
                _send_notification(monitor, last_result)
```

I already tried to put a for loop around the 'check_html' function that iterates over every object in monitor but that just returns that monitors can't be iterated over. it was a long shot but still didn't work

Comment: What error did you get with the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have passed the queryset to the `check_html()` function. Using a filter we get one or more items that are iterable. You can use the for loop in `check_html()` function or password only one object to the function.

Comment: but if I try to put a for loop around the check html funtion like 'for monitor in monitors' it give me this error 'TypeError: 'Monitor' object is not iterable'

Comment: Can You show the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had added the `check_html` function to run on a certain command. Which at the end of the script tried to give the whole queryset to the `check_html` function itself.

So I just had to remove the `check_html` function from `run_monitor`.

Thank you for your help guys.